# group_start in codeigniter throwing error

Tags: php

I am trying to implementing server side pagination but in search it throws error and does'not shows any response here is a screenshot[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJS2y.png)

here is my code so far i have implemeted:
view:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    table = $('#posts').DataTable({ 
//"lengthMenu": [ [10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"] ],
        "processing": true, 
        "serverSide": true, 
        "order": [], //Initial no order.

        // Load data for the table's content from an Ajax source
        "ajax": {
            "url": "<?php echo base_url('app/ajax_list')?>",
            "type": "POST",
              "dataType": "json",
              "data":{  '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>' : '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>' }

        },

        //Set column definition initialisation properties.
        "columnDefs": [
        { 
            "targets": [ 0 ], //first column / numbering column
            "orderable": false, //set not orderable
        },
        ],

    });
});
```

controller:

```
public function ajax_list()
    {
        $list = $this->app_model->get_datatables();
        $data = array();
        $no = $_POST['start'];
         foreach ($list as $post)
            {   
        $row = array();  
        $row[]='<div class="tbcell"></div>';    
        $row[] ='<div class="tbcell">'. $post->empid.'</div>';
        $row[] = '<div class="tbcell">'.$post->Name.'</div>';
        $row[] = '<div class="tbcell">'.$post->punchdate.'</div>';
        $row[] = '<div class="tbcell">'.$post->first_punch.'</div>';
        if($post->first_punch==$post->last_punch)
                {
                    $last_punch='-';
                }else
                {
                    $last_punch=$post->last_punch;
                }
        $row[] = '<div class="tbcell">'.$last_punch.'</div>';
        $row[]='<div class="tbcell">'.$post->duration.'</div>';
        $row[]='<div class="tbcell">'.$post->location_name.'</div>';
                                    $punch_distance=$post->punch_distance;
                                    $punch_status=$post->punch_status;
                                    $arr_status=explode(',',$punch_status);
                                    $arr_distance=explode(',',$punch_distance);

                                    $c = array_combine($arr_status, $arr_distance);

                                    foreach($c as $key=>$value)
                                            {
                                              $key_value=$key;
                                              if($key_value==1)
                                              {

                                                 $row[] = '<div class="tbcell">'.$value.'</div>';
                                              } else
                                              {
                                                   $row[] = '<div class="tbcell">-</div>';
                                              }

                                            }

                                            foreach($c as $key=>$value1)
                                            {
                                              $key_value=$key;
                                              if($key_value==2)
                                              {
                                                 $row[] ='<div class="tbcell">'. $value1.'</div>';
                                              } 
                                              else if($key_value==1)
                                              {
                                                   $row[] = '<div class="tbcell">-</div>';
                                              } else
                                              {
                                                  $row[] = '<div class="tbcell">-</div>';
                                              }
                                            }

                                            $office=$post->office;
                                    if($office=='OD')
                                    {
                                        //echo '<div style="color:red" class="tbcell">';
                                        foreach($c as $key=>$value)
                                            {
                                              $key_value=$key;
                                              if($key_value==3)
                                              {
                                                 $row[] ='<div style="color:red" class="tbcell">'.$office.'</div>'; 
                                              }
                                               else if($key_value==2)
                                              {
                                                   $row[] = '<div style="color:red" class="tbcell">-</div>';
                                              }
                                            else if($key_value==1)
                                              {
                                                   $row[] = '<div style="color:red" class="tbcell">-</div>';
                                              } else
                                              {
                                                  $row[] = '<div style="color:red" class="tbcell">-</div>';
                                              }
                                            }
                                    }else
                                    {
                                        //echo '<div class="tbcell">';
                                         $row[] ='<div class="tbcell">'.$office.'</div>';
                                        //echo '<div>';
                                    }
        $row[]='<div class="tbcell"><a href="'.base_url().'reports/attendance_track/'.$post->empid.'/'.$post->punchdate.'">Details</a></div> ';
        //$row[] = '<a href="'.base_url().'event-edit/'.$value->id.'" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">Edit</a>';
        $data[] = $row;


            }

        $output = array(
                        "draw" => $_POST['draw'],
                        "recordsTotal" => $this->app_model->allposts_count(),
                        "recordsFiltered" => $this->app_model->count_filtered(),
                        "data" => $data,
                );
        //output to json format
        echo json_encode($output);
    }
```

model:

```
function _get_datatables_query()
  { //term is value of $_REQUEST['search']['value']
                $project_id = $this->session->userdata['dcnine_session']['project_id'];
                $column_search =array('att.emp_id','u.Name','date_format(att.added_date, "%d-%m-%Y")','a.location_name');
                $column_order = array('att.emp_id','u.Name','date_format(att.added_date, "%d-%m-%Y")','min(att.added_date)','max(att.added_date)','TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,min(att.added_date),max(att.added_date))','a.location_name',NULL,NULL,'case when punch_status = 3 then "OD" ELSE "Office" end as office','p.signature_image','group_concat(att.punch_status)','group_concat(att.punch_distance)','att.id');
                $this->db->_protect_identifiers=false;
                $order = array('date_format(att.added_date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s")' => 'desc');

                $this->db->select('p.signature_image,group_concat(att.punch_status) as punch_status,group_concat(att.punch_distance) as "punch_distance",u.Name,att.emp_id as empid,att.id,date_format(att.added_date,"%d-%m-%Y") as "punchdate",max(att.added_date) as last_punch,min(att.added_date) as first_punch,TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,min(att.added_date),max(att.added_date)) as duration,a.location_name,case when punch_status = 3 then "OD" ELSE "Office" end as office');
                $this->db->from('pmc_attendance as att,tbl_admin_users u,tbl_attendance a,tbl_attendance_photo p');

                  $this->db->where('u.project_id',$project_id);
                  $this->db->where('u.emp_id','att.emp_id',FALSE);
                  $this->db->where('a.id','u.location_id',FALSE);
                  $this->db->where('p.pmc_id','att.id',FALSE);
                   $this->db->where('u.project_id','att.project_id',FALSE);
                  $this->db->where('u.project_id','a.project_id',FALSE);

                  $this->db->where('MONTH(att.added_date) ','MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())',FALSE);
                  $this->db->where_not_in('u.location_id','1');
                   $this->db->where('u.project_id','att.project_id',FALSE);
                  $this->db->where('u.project_id','a.project_id',FALSE);
                  $this->db->group_by('att.emp_id,date_format(att.added_date,"%Y-%m-%d")');


                 // $this->db->order_by('date_format(att.added_date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s")',"desc");
                $i = 0;
                    //print_r($column_search);
                    //die;

                foreach ($column_search as $item) // loop column
                {
                    //echo $_POST['search']['value'];die;

                    if($_POST['search']['value']) // if datatable send POST for search
                    {

                        if($i===0) // first loop
                        {
                                //die("1");
                                $this->db->group_start(); 

                                $this->db->like($item, $_POST['search']['value']);

                        }
                        else
                        {
                                //die("2");
                                $this->db->or_like($item, $_POST['search']['value']);
                        }

                       if(count($column_search) - 1 == $i) 
                        $this->db->group_end(); 

                    }

                 $i++;
             }

                if(isset($_POST['order'])) // here order processing
                {

                     $this->db->order_by($column_order[$_POST['order']['0']['column']], $_POST['order']['0']['dir']);
                }
                else if(isset($this->order))
                {
                     /*$order = $this->order;*/

                     $this->db->order_by(key($order), $order[key($order)]);
                }

            }


        function get_datatables()
        {
            $this->_get_datatables_query();
            if($_POST['length'] != -1)  $this->db->limit(10, $_POST['start']);
            $query = $this->db->get();
            return ($query->num_rows() > 0) ?   $query->result()    :   false;
        }
        function count_filtered()
    {
        $this->_get_datatables_query();
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->num_rows();
    }
```

so far i understand that is group_start() creating a problem if i comment this line from my code it takes long time to load and throws error "Incorrect key file for table '/tmp/#sql_a37_18.MYI'; try to repair it". unable to identify what is the problem

Comment: Please edit your question so that all code is inside code blocks.

Comment: @pradeep: nothing works